# netstat process name information programmatically or from procfs

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have a requirement to get all the port numbers that a particular program is listening on.  The program itself is a generic server type program (lets call it `myserverd`). `myserverd` can be configured to listen on any TCP port, and there can be more than one instance of `myserverd` running on a machine.

I can get the ports being used by running instances of `myserverd` by `grep`'ing for `myserverd` in `netstat -natp` (`p` option to display the program name in `netstat`)

I am trying to see this information in procfs (`/proc/net/tcp`) but it doesn't show any process names... my question is: is there a good/reliable API that can be used to programmatically figure out what processes are listening to a particular port (or get all process names bound to all listening ports)... ?

Comment: http://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/iphlpapi/iphlpapi_main.c#L1842

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for a *nix/posix solution (hence my 'linux' tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code for netstat here: https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/master/networking/netstat.c. If you look through it, you should see how netstat gets the pids/names of bound processes.

Specifically, look at the `prg_cache_load()` function, as `netstat` just polls `/proc/net/tcp` anyway.

Comment: I've updated the link to a mirror of the master busybox project, which (hopefully) shouldn't go down.